# "Warning: You have '~/.profile' file" when installing RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm

In following http://installrails.com/steps/install_rvm_and_ruby

This is the output I get:

```
~/code/ruby \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    720      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   721
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  11941      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 20676
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/adamzerner/.profile /Users/adamzerner/.bashrc /Users/adamzerner/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile /Users/adamzerner/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/ is complete.

# Adam Zerner,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:


  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile

  * No new notes to display.

~/code/ruby type rvm | head -n 1
-bash: type: rvm: not found
~/code/ruby
```

Yesterday I had went through the InstallRails guide, and everything worked perfectly. I had RVM installed, Rails installed, Ruby installed etc. Then I had to change the Ruby version because one of my sites was using an older version of Ruby (not sure how I did this though).

Now, somehow it seems that RVM and Rails aren't installed. What do I do?

**Edit:**

I moved the contents of `.profile` to `.bash_profile`, changed the name of `.profile` to `.pprofile`, and ran `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` again. It gave me the error: `RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.`. I did that, and the it gave me the error `WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it` again. It seems that `--auto-dotfiles` creates a `.profile` file.

```
~ open .profile
~ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    596      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   595
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  26570      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26570
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/adamzerner/.bashrc /Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile /Users/adamzerner/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/adamzerner/.zlogin.
    RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/ is complete.

# Adam Zerner,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

~ type rvm | head -n 1
-bash: type: rvm: not found
~ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    791      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   793
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  44948      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 44948
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/
    Removing rvm PATH line from /Users/adamzerner/.bashrc /Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile /Users/adamzerner/.zshrc.
    Adding rvm PATH line to /Users/adamzerner/.profile /Users/adamzerner/.bashrc /Users/adamzerner/.zshrc.
    Removing rvm loading line from /Users/adamzerner/.zlogin.
    Adding rvm loading line to /Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile /Users/adamzerner/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/ is complete.

# Adam Zerner,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:


  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile

  * No new notes to display.

~ ls -a
.           .gitconfig      Desktop
..          .heroku         Documents
.CFUserTextEncoding .irb-history        Downloads
.DS_Store       .netrc          Dropbox
.Trash          .pprofile       Library
.bash_history       .profile        Movies
.bash_profile       .rvm            Music
.bashrc         .ssh            Pictures
.dropbox        .zlogin         Public
.dropbox-master     .zshrc          code
.gem            Applications
~
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what the warning says?

Comment: Yea, sorry I forgot to mention that. My `.bash_profile` file now shows that line in it.

Answer (score 5):

may this can help you, bc it seems to be exactly the same problem:

This warning says you have a file `~/.profile` - this file is loaded as a last resort in Bash when there is no `~/.bash_profile` - and the installer found both files, this means that you might be expecting some configuration from `~/.profile` to be available on shell start but it would not be because it was not read. To fix the problem you can either

1. remove `~/.profile` (in case you do not use it),
2. move content of `~/.profile` to `~/.bash_profile`, or
3. add the folowing line to `~/.bash_profile` (you need to edit the file): source `~/.profile`

Source: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2832

Comment: I added the content of `.profile` to `.bash_profile`, but it still isn't working (giving me the same errors). Should I delete `.profile` after moving its content to `.bash_profile`?

Comment: better rename it - and test again :)

Answer (score 3):

For me this works:

replace:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

with:

```
source "$HOME/.profile" # Also loads RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Source: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2832

Answer (score 2):

Replace content of /Users/Akorn/.bash_profile 
with

> source ~/.profile

Method:

```
1) travel to folder: cd ~/
2) list only hidden files: ls -ld .?*  
3) edit file: pico .bash_profile
4) replace content
5) save
```

Comment: is this an Answer or is this a new question of yours ?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. I am very excited to earn my second bronze point!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran:

```
source /Users/my_user_name/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

in the terminal and that solved the issue. Hope that helps.